# when I run the pyaudio program I got this error, how can l resolve this

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

I got the error

`Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/huangjinxue/Documents/python/workspace/pyMusic/music-pyaudio.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_portaudio.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_portaudio.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup`

How can i resolve it, i want to use pyaudio play music list

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from the error messages that you are on either OS-X or Linux - in either case you have an unmet dependency on the [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) package.

You need to either install it from your package manager or to download, build & install it from [here](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html).

Comment: yes  i do it through brew and also from download source,and on the mac, but it still dont work

Comment: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html may be of some help. It looks like you may have competing versions of python.